# sort() - No matching function for call to 'swap'

Tags: c++, xcode, sorting, compiler-errors, swap

Just spent about an hour trying to figure out why I would get 20 error messages of the type `"Semantic issue - no matching function for call to 'swap'"` when I try to build the following class (in XCode).

**test.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Test{
    std::vector<std::string> list;

    void run() const;
    static bool algo(const std::string &str1, const std::string &str2);
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"


void Test::run() const {
    std::sort( list.begin(), list.end(), algo );
}


bool Test::algo(const std::string &str1, const std::string &str2){
    // Compare and return bool
}
```

Most of the people with the same problem seem to have made their algorithm a class member instead of a static member, but that is clearly not the problem here.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It turns out it's a very simple problem, but not very obvious to spot (and the error message doesn't do a very good job in helping out either):

Remove the `const` declaration on `run()` - voilá.

Comment: The error message should at least point in the right direction, but you have to check the full text of the error not just what XCode shows inline.

Answer (score 16):

The compiler refers to `swap` because `std::sort` internally uses function swap. However as member function `run` is declared as constant function

```
void run() const;
```

then the object of the class itself is considered as a constant object and hence data member list also is a constant object

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
```

So the compiler tries to call `swap` with parameters that are constant references or even are not references and can not find such a function.