# error: no matching function for call to 'swap'

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11, quicksort, swap

I am trying to sort cakeTypes vector by the size of their weight. But getting the error in sort implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CakeType 
{
public:
    const unsigned int weight_;
    const unsigned int value_;

    CakeType(unsigned int weight = 0, unsigned int value = 0) :
        weight_(weight),
        value_(value)
    {}
};

bool compareCakes(const CakeType& cake1, const CakeType& cake2) {
    return cake1.weight_ < cake2.weight_;
}


unsigned long long maxDuffelBagValue(const std::vector<CakeType>& cakeTypes,
                                     unsigned int weightCapacity)
{
    // calculate the maximum value that we can carry
    unsigned cakeTypesSize = cakeTypes.size();
    unsigned long long valueCalculator[weightCapacity+1][cakeTypesSize+1];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<=weightCapacity+1; i++) {
        valueCalculator[i][0] = 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<=cakeTypesSize+1; i++) {
        valueCalculator[0][i] = 0;
    }
    vector<CakeType> sortedCakeTypes(cakeTypes);


    sort(sortedCakeTypes.begin(), sortedCakeTypes.end(), compareCakes);
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of there error:

> exited with non-zero code (1).
>
> In file included from solution.cc:1:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/string:439:
>   /usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:3856:17: error: no matching function for call to 'swap'
>
> > ```
> >             swap(*__first, *__last);
> >
> >             ^~~~
> > ```

I tried this solution [sort() - No matching function for call to 'swap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761802/sort-no-matching-function-for-call-to-swap), but it is not the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort() - No matching function for call to 'swap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761802/sort-no-matching-function-for-call-to-swap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data type which is used by `swap` function in `sort` algorithm must be `MoveAssignable`, then you can perform operation like below

```
CakeType c1, c2;
c1 = move(c2); // <- move c2 to c1
```

But in your case `CakeType` has const data members. You can assign values to const data members only in constructors. Code cannot be compiled because default move/copy assignment operator can't be generated by this restriction (assignment to const member is illegal).

Remove const specifier from your class definition and code will work.

```
class CakeType 
{
public:
    unsigned int weight_;
    unsigned int value_;

    CakeType(unsigned int weight = 0, unsigned int value = 0) :
        weight_(weight),
        value_(value)
    {}
};
```

Comment: So it is closely related to the possible duplicate after all.